# Vector class: Difference between 4 floats, or array of 4 floats

Tags: c++, game-engine

Dear StackOverflowers,

I have read a few books and saw different examples for Vector classes.
Now I was wondering:
Is there a difference in performance or portability (or anything else excluding access) in:

```
class Vector
{
public:
        ....
private:
    float mTuple[4];
};
```

And

```
class Vector
{
public:
        ....
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;
};
```

I think Vector.x is a more elegant solution then Vector.X();
I know that overloading the operator [] will then be a little more complicated,
but I think the compiler should easily be able to optimize it to the same speed,
and it will not noticed by the user of the Vector class.

What do you guys think about this?

Christian

Comment: I think modern compilers can and will do the optimization if the implementation of the getter is in the header.

Comment: The first one is not portable unless you really meant `float mTuple[4];`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I ment that. Since a short while the four and five keys on my laptop don't work so I accidentally use them sometimes without getting them on there. I edited it by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, although both are portable and as performant, they really don't have the same meaning.

If you know you will always have 4 elements in your array and they have a different semantic (e.g., coordinates x, y & z in a 3D space), your second solution is probably better, although giving public access to fields is not good practice (and is no more performant, as your compiler can inline bother trivial getters and setters).

If your vector can have any (reasonable) number of items, obviously you have no choice but use a `float[]` or a `float*` (edit : or, more C++-like, a `std::vector` or `std::array`).

Comment: Thanks of the comment! Normally public access wouldn't be desired. But in this case when using a Vector with fixed x,y,z,w coordinates I think it would be better right? Or do you think it's better if I made it private and would return only pass-by-value floats from the access functions?

Comment: @Fabien: of course you have a choice, you could easily use a `std::vector<float>` or `std::dyn_array<float>` or even a `std::deque<float>`. And any of those would probably be preferable to `float*`.

Comment: @Fabien Just one more question: Is there a reason to protect the access to the x,y,z,w variables? Shouldn't a vector's coordinates be modifiable by the user? Or would a vector in a game engine better be ONLY modified by operators like multiplication and addition. Aren't there cases where direct access to variables is preferred?

Comment: There are of course good/bad sides to both allowing direct access and "hiding" the access behind getter/setter functions. If we assume that these values are going to be used in other functions, the extra accessors will make it harder to read, I think: `if (a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y + a.z * a.z > b.x * b.x + b.y * b.y + b.z * b.z)` is "better" than `if (a.X() * a.X() + a.Y() * a.Y() + a.Z() + a.Z() * a.Z() > b.X() * b.X() + b.Y() * b.Y() + b.Z() * b.Z())` (yes, this probably should be a function, but that's a different matter)

Comment: @ChristianVeenman It really depends on the context, there is no better solution, only trade-offs. Most of the time, when possible, you should aim at having non-mutable objects, i.e. private members and only getters, no setter. It's much easier to deal with, maintain and test, but sometimes performance requirements forbid it, and sometimes it would actually make the overall solution more complicated. If you want a mutable vector, having public x, y & z is probably an acceptable solution.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I was not sure the goal was to implement a vector class as an exercise or not, so then using the predefined `vector` would be cheating. If that is not the case, using `std` containers over raw C arrays is always preferable.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I've got the answer to my question!

Comment: @Fabien: I think the author is using Vector in the mathematical/physical sense, as the names x, y, z, w imply.

Answer (score 0):

As already has been said, portable are both ways, but giving access to members like this is not good practice, unless you are desperate for performance.

However, accessing the array, the compiler loads the base pointer and adds the value to access it. In the other case, using a getter, the compiler generates directly the code to access the adress of the variable.

So for accessing the array, there are two instructions needed at minimum, while in the other case only one is needed. Not sure if this really gets optimized though. I wouldn't bet on it, and if your live depends on it, you should make sure that the code does what you want it to, instead of relying on the output of the compiler.

Comment: Mmm don't almost all architecture provide a memory addressing mode like (Base + Index) which doesn't take any extra cycles?

Comment: The base address of the array has to be loaded into the register, then the index in another one and then you can use the baseaddress plus index instructon. The optimization could be that the compiler calculates the base as the address of the array form the object adress, but I'm not sure if this would really be done.